# Does more instances means more connections?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I am trying to build a messaging app such that each message will be inserted to the database. Also, my backend will hit the database every second to retrieve the latest messages. I am worried that if I have many users who are using the messages feature, I will hit the database maximum number of connection quickly and the app will not work for other users. So, how can I make sure this problem will not happen?

- I am just wondering if I created two (db-g1-small) instances, will I have twice the number of connection (1000 per instance)?. Google documentation says (db-g1-small) 1,000 Maximum Connections.
- How can I keep track of the number of connections?. What will happen if the number of connection to the database reaches the maximum?

https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing#2nd-gen-instance-pricing

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have a unique connection per user to your database. Instead, your backend should use connection pooling to maintain a consistent number of connections to your instance. You can view some example of how best to do this on the [Managing Database Connections](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/manage-connections) page.

It's incredibly unlikely that you'll need 1000 open connections. Most applications use far, far less for optimal performance. You can check out [this article about benchmarking different connection pool sizes.](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing)

Comment: I open and close the connection every time I make a query, so the connection is not persistent. So, if google cloud offer 1,000, would it be enough for my application? given that the application has more features that need the database as well.

Comment: What I'm trying to tell you is you should NOT open and close a connection for each query - use a connection pool. When you "open" a connection from a pool it gives you an already established one, and when you "close" the connection it is returned to the pool until a different part of your application needs it. There is a ton of overhead associated with opening and closing connections - reusing connections will not only give you more throughput, but will lower latency as well.

Comment: Sorry If I didn't made my question clear. What I say I open and close connection, I meant a cursor. Basically, I open a connection when my flask application starts, and I use it to open a cursor, excuse a query and finally close the cursor before return the results.

Comment: Consider using Flask-SQLAlchemy - it's a great connection pool, and has integrations for flask: https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/

There are example of using SQLAlchemy on the page I linked to you.